# One leg seems to be doing all the work when squatting

Tags: squats

When I'm doing squat, I feel the right leg I have is doing a lot more work lifting up the weight than my left leg. What can I do so that both legs contribute equally?

Answer (score 2):

If the bar is centred on your back and your hips are centred between your feet, then your legs are contributing equally.

You need to consider that you aren't actually capable of perceiving how much work each leg is doing, only how fatigued each leg is getting. It's easy to mistake one leg being weaker than the other and getting fatigued more easily for that leg doing more work. And then trying to compensate by shifting more weight onto the leg that you feel is doing less work, or doing extra unilateral exercises for that leg, will only make the problem worse.

The correct way to deal with this perceived imbalance is to make sure the bar is centred, and then ignore the feeling of the workload not being balanced. If you do have one leg that's weaker than the other, this will help it catch up.

Comment: One might also consider incorporating some unilateral work, just because. Lunges or split squats. Great stuff.

Comment: One could, but with the caveat that these should be done with an equal weight and number of reps for each side, rather than doing them as a "corrective" exercise where they're only done for the leg that is (possibly incorrectly) perceived to be weaker.